# How to use signalR on SharePoint timer job

Tags: sharepoint, timer, signalr

I have a requirement as below.

Clients will be connected with a SignalR Hub by accessing the SharePoint Web.

**Requirement#1**
I should be able to send notification to clients when an event occurs on the web site and I am able to.

**Requirement#2**
I should also be able to send notifications to clients when a timer job runs - I find it impossible.

Any suggestions? How do I send notifications to clients when a timer job runs?

**Update#1**
As I uses Sql backplane, thought of using setting up the Dependency Resolver on Timer Job as mentioned below

```
 GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString.ConnectionString);
```

however it throws an exception - The name 'GlobalHost' does not exist in the current context.